# C# and NoSql databases

Tags: c#, database, nosql

Is there any particular NoSQL database suitable for C#?

Thank you!

Comment: Given that the protocols are usually pretty simple and language/platform agnostic, why would any be particularly appropriate **or** inappropriate?

Comment: @Marc: One could say the same about SQL, and yet MSSQL is vastly better supported by Linq-to-SQL than any other RDBMS...

Comment: @Daniel: what are you trying to achieve with NoSQL?

Comment: @Dyppl: What I'm trying to achieve is to minimize the number of products within the area to know where to start. I mean there seem to be a zillion NoSQL databases out there.

Comment: @Timwi: this is why Microsoft are no longer investing in LINQ to SQL

Comment: @timwi and to know if l2s is a fit you need to know what you want to achieve... Te same applies to nosql - you need a comparitor.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What NoSQL solutions are out there for .NET?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1777103/what-nosql-solutions-are-out-there-for-net)

Comment: I recommend trying dbreeze too. Very advanced features. no dependencies. Fully managed code. ACID.

Comment: Another option to consider: Mehdi Gholam's RaptorDB: https://github.com/mgholam/RaptorDB-Document https://www.codeproject.com/articles/375413/raptordb-the-document-store

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I agree with Marc's comment above, but I guess what you're looking for is probably something like [RavenDB](http://ravendb.net/).  It's developed specifically with .NET in mind, so would probably seem more "C# friendly" than others such as CouchDB or MongoDB, etc.

Keep in mind, however, that the different NoSQL implementations have different strengths and weaknesses beyond simply what language/platform is more natively considered during their development.  It may very well be true that RavenDB would seem more natural to a .NET developer, but a different database may be better suited to the job at hand depending on the data persistence needs.

Here's [a quick breakdown](http://nosql.mypopescu.com/post/978742866/document-databases-compared-couchdb-mongodb-ravendb) of some other feature comparisons that I just found.  As you can see there's more to each tool than its .NET driver.  A little Googling of NoSQL database comparisons will yield more information.  If you have more specific data persistence needs or can elaborate more on the project in question we may be able to provide more advice.

**Edit:** (In response to your comment above)  To perhaps help you narrow down your choices, here's my experience so far:

Of the three that I've mentioned, the only one I've actually used in .NET is MongoDB.  It didn't "feel" as native for .NET purposes, but it wasn't difficult or unwieldy in any way.  It was easy enough to use and performed its intended task very well.

I've used CouchDB from JavaScript code, as opposed to from .NET code.  It's considered to be a very JavaScript friendly database and I've been toying with the idea of connecting to it directly from client-side AJAX calls.  But it should be just as easy from within .NET.  That's the beauty of a RESTful API, really.  Anything should be able to interact with it as easily as interacting with any service.  From within .NET code, something like RestSharp may make using CouchDB very easy and feel more .NET-native.

Comment: this was the kind of answer I was looking for. A "C# friendly" was even better explained than originally posted. :-D

Comment: Just a quick note on that comparison from the provided link; RavenDB now supports ad-hoc queries.

Answer (score 8):

Pure C# free and open-source NoSql [DBreeze database](http://dbreeze.codeplex.com)

Comment: I've used DBreeze - it's not performant and persists files as its storage medium - resulting in incredibly poor performance once you reach over 10,000 reasonably complex (as in has children) objects.

Answer (score 7):

MSDN Magazine had a sequence of articles by Ted Steward on using MongoDB from C# around May-July 2010.

- [Part One](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ee310029.aspx)
- [Part Two](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ff714592.aspx)
- [Part Three](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ff798277.aspx)

Comment: thank you, sounds interesting.

Answer (score 2):

Mongo recently released and is subsequently supporting a native C# driver. Source code is on Github. See here for more details: http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/CSharp+Language+Center

Answer (score 0):

[EgoDB](https://www.nuget.org/packages/EgoDB) is another one,simple, thread safe, multi-process  written in plain c#

Comment: The project looks abandoned now. The last NuGet release was a year ago and the domain is up for sale.

Comment: https://github.com/hhblaze/DBreeze

Comment: This was a project i was working on, I have added a recommendation in the nuget for anyone not to use it anylonger. I have tried  DBreeze that @juFo suggested and had success with it